# Twitter deep link in android

Tags: android, twitter, deep-linking

I have implemented deep linking for my app in android. It works using facebook or browser. But when i share to twitter and click link from twitter apps, it doesn't open app but open twitter browser.

Anyone get issue like this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Twitter's Webview is custom, and doesn't allow you to fire a URI scheme directly from their webview, using the `window`. Here's a [post](https://twittercommunity.com/t/cannot-open-app-with-url-scheme-from-twitters-web-view/21617) on their dev community forums.

If you use a 3rd party service like [Branch](http://branch.io?bmp=stackoverflow), you can offload handling edge cases like this (Full disclosure, I work there). Branch's solution was as follows:

- template a new page if the user agent was Twitter's mobile webview
- Inside new page, have some sort of `<a href>` behind a button that either fires the URI scheme or redirects to App/Play store.

Comment: i am using Branch for sharing actually i have both app in android and ios but facebook and other app working properly but getting issue in Twitter its move to playstore for download app when click on share link on twitter. how can i resolved this

Answer (score 0):

In the **LinkProperties** object of branch use the **control parameter** `$android_deeplink_path` and put value `<your custom host>` like `abcd.app.link`.